# fillna() produces NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I am using the following code to fill the `NaN` values and then adding a column to the `DataFrame` which would contain the number of values in a row which are greater than 0. Here's the code:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
dfMin10 = df
dfMin10['Sum'] = (dfMin10.iloc[1:len(dfMin10.columns)] > 0).sum(1)
dfMin10
```

When I see the column `Sum`, I still see some `NaN` values. Why would this be? I'm assuming my `DataFrame (df)` also has some `NaN` values even after replacing `NaN`.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you seeing `NaN` in the first `sum` entry? This line:

```
branchConceptsWithScoresMin10['Sum'] = (branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.iloc[1:len(branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.columns)] > 0).sum(1)
```

Should this be:

```
branchConceptsWithScoresMin10['Sum'] = (branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.iloc[0:len(branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.columns)] > 0).sum(1)
```

Note the indexing starting from `0`.

**Example**:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
branchConceptsWithScoresMin10 = df
# Your original code
branchConceptsWithScoresMin10['Sum'] = (branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.iloc[1:len(branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.columns)] > 0).sum(1)

# This should return
# a  b  c  d  Sum
# x  0  0  0  0  NaN
# y  0  0  0  0  0.0
# z  0  0  0  0  0.0

branchConceptsWithScoresMin10['Sum'] = (branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.iloc[0:] > 0).sum(1)

# There should not be any NaNs here.
```

Comment: You're right, I was seeing it in the first entry. But I'm also seeing `NaN` in the last many entries. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ahh, I was doing something silly. IT should have been `branchConceptsWithScoresMin10['Sum'] = (branchConceptsWithScoresMin10.iloc[0:] > 0).sum(1)`. Now it works.

Comment: Have a look at your dataframe before you do the sum for a row where you are getting `NaN` and that should give you some idea. If you post it in your question, we can try and help.

Comment: Cool. Glad it's sorted.